# How to find the second largest number in for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num;
    int large;
    int small;
    int secondLarge;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input a number: ");
    num = scan.nextInt();
    large = num;
    small = num;
    secondLarge = num;

    for (int x = 9; x > 0; x--) {
        System.out.print("Enter " + x + " more number: ");
        num = scan.nextInt();

        if (num > large) {
            large = num;

        }
        if (num > secondLarge) {
            secondLarge = num;
        }

        if (secondLarge > large) {
            large = secondLarge;

        }
        if (num < small) {
            small = num;

        }

    } System.out.println( large + " is the largest number, " + secondLarge + " is the second largest number and " + small + " is the smallest number!");
}
```

So, I'm trying to output the largest number, second largest, and smallest. I'm able to get the smallest and largest but have no clue where to begin to get the second biggest. I thought this would work but its outputting the same thing as large. I'm currently not suppose to use arrays as this is homework. Please don't tell me the exact answer, but some help and hints would be wonderful!

Comment: Why not read the numbers to an array, then sort the numbers?

Comment: @EvanBechtol "I'm currently not suppose to use arrays as this is homework"

Comment: Jonnie mentioned that he cannot use arrays in his solution.

Comment: You will need to deal with the second largest in the `else` section of the largest.

Comment: My mistake! Over-looked that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize Variables like

```
int largest=0;
int secondlargest=0;
int smallest=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Condition should be like

```
if(number>=largest){
    secondlargest=largest;
    largest=number;
}else if(number>secondlargest){
    secondlargest=number;
}
if(number<smallest){
    smallest=number;
}
```

Comment: Why is smallest set to Integer.max_value   ?

Comment: @Evan Bechtol  Because when comparing, we compare smallest with current number and if current number is smaller than smallest , we change smallest to current number value. so at the beginning smallest should be the highest

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution using static methods max and min from class Math:

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        int input, largest = 0, secondLargest = 0, smallest = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Input an integer number:");
            input = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

            secondLargest = Math.min(largest, Math.max(input, secondLargest));
            largest = Math.max(input, largest);
            smallest = Math.min(input, smallest)
        }

        System.out.println("Largest integer number entered was: " + largest);
        System.out.println("Second largest integer number entered was: " + secondLargest);
        System.out.println("Smallest integer number entered was: " + smallest);
    }
}
```

Comment: you solution is missing the smallest one.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int max = 0;
    int smax = 0;
    int num = 0;
    while (num != -1) {
        System.out.println("Enter number  Or -1 to Stop:");
        num = in.nextInt();
        if (num >= max) {
            smax = max;
            max = num;
        } 
    }
    
    System.out.println("second max :"+smax);

}
```